# Grails Acegi Url mapping weirdness

Tags: grails, spring-security

This is Grails 1.2.0 and Acegi 0.5.2.

Part of my security config (the requestMapString):

```
requestMapString = """\
        CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
        PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT
        /login/auth=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        /logout/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        /role/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        /js/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        /css/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        /images/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        /plugins/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        /captcha/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        /register/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        /help/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        /=IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY
        /**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY
        """
```

I also had the '/' rule at the top, which did not make any difference.  In my logs, I see lines like

```
2010-11-15 14:08:02,937 DEBUG FilterChainProxy - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/images/nav_bg_ribbon_hover.png'; to: '/images/nav_bg_ribbon_hover.png'
2010-11-15 14:08:02,938 DEBUG FilterChainProxy - Candidate is: '/images/nav_bg_ribbon_hover.png'; pattern is /**; matched=true
```

which indicates the URL does not match correctly.  What am I doing wrong here?